# Not being able to use Jquery.contains() for checking nested <ul> in <li>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, conditional-formatting

### Main issue |  `$.contains(arg1, arg2)`

I'm not able to get the `$.contains()` to work.
I want to check if the `<li>` has a nested `<ul class="sub-menu">` but no matter what format I put the arguments in I always get an output of `false`. (want to eventually wrap that in a if statement to edit some CSS)

#### More info  below

### JS

```
$( document ).ready(navSecondary());
function navSecondary(){
  var firstListSize = $("nav.header-secondary>ul>li").length;
  for (var i = 0; i < firstLiSize; i++) {
    var nav = $("nav.header-secondary>ul>li:nth-child("+i+1+")");
    var sub = document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("ul");
    var check = $.contains(sub,nav);
    console.log(check);
  }
}
```

### HTML

```
<nav class="header-secondary">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item 1</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub Option 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Option 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Option 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here I want to be able to conditionally edit css using Js + Jquery (the Codepen has the basic css)

### [Codepen (Just for reference :)))](https://codepen.io/Fofandi/pen/dyYrWrp)

### Some background

So I'm creating a theme on WordPress and want to use WordPress's inbuild menu manager, I don't want to go through the hassle of asking WordPress to create classes for each list item and sub menu list so on and so forth. 
EDIT- I realize there is an easier way to do the CSS (through the classes WordPress would add to the menu items) but I wanted to try and do it through Jquery

Comment: `$( document ).ready(navSecondary())` should be `$( document ).ready(navSecondary);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(navSecondary());
function navSecondary(){
  var list = $("nav.header-secondary>ul>li");
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var check = list[i].children.length > 1;
    console.log(check)
  }
}
```

Once you get the list with $("nav.header-secondary>ul>li") you can use that one to iterate and check its content :)

---

If you specifically want to find the ul tag

```
$( document ).ready(navSecondary());
function navSecondary(){
  var list = $("nav.header-secondary>ul>li");
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var check = [...list[i].children].some(c => c.tagName == "UL")
    console.log(check)
  }
}
```

Comment: Yea that works like a charm, I'm VERY new to JS and JQ didn't realize you could use .lenght with children/nested things.

if its not too much trouble could explain why the `$.contains()` doesn't work the way i was doing it? 

thanks a lot for the ans tho :))

Comment: but this will give you an error if you decide to use icon or imga in your list tag for icon menus while icon or image is also children. You need to choose children whose tag is ul

Comment: (other than `firstListSize` with a typo in the for condition)